# Check for an existing record - PHP

Tags: php

If a user creates a group and that group doesn't exist, then create that group; but if it already exists, send a message saying so.

This my code. It inserts into my database but cannot check if a group already exists.

```
<?php

    mysql_connect('localhost','root','');

    mysql_select_db('test');

    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM groups WHERE name!="'.misc::escape($_POST['name']).'"');

    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
    {

       $sql="INSERT INTO groups(name) VALUES ('$_POST[name]')";

       mysql_query($sql);

       $select_result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM groups WHERE name='$_POST[name]' ");

       $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($select_result);

       echo($row['id']);

    }

    else

    {

      echo("this group exist");

    }

?>
```

Comment: You should start from scratch and read a PHP/MySQL tutorial.

Comment: And pay close attention to the section about SQL injection attacks.

Comment: look into isset() http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [mysql_num_rows](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) to count the number of rows returned by a query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM groups WHERE name != '$_POST[name]'");
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
{
     // create new group
}
else
{
     // print an error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if("SELECT * FROM groups WHERE name!=('$_POST[name]')")
```

You're creating an if-statement that checks if your string is true. For the above case, it will always be true. I assume what you really want to is to send that string as a query to your database, in which case you should use `mysql_query()` as you to later in your code.

But on the other hand, that query makes no sense at all even if it was executed. It selects (if it wasn't for the obvious syntax error involving parenthesis) every row from the database where the name is not `$_POST[name]`.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO groups(name) VALUES ('$_POST[name]')";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Here, you insert values to your database and that actually works OK, except that you're completely vulnerable to SQL injections.

**So to summarize: Go read a basic tutorial on PHP and MySQL.**